# Perl Regex - Replace the ending of sentences to be period, one whitespace, capital letter

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to develop a regex that will replace messy sentence endings with cleaner ones.

For example, turning:

```
the quick.brown fox. jumped over! the slow.  dog
```

Into:

```
The quick. Brown fox. Jumped over. The slow. Dog
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
my $test = ucfirst('the quick.brown fox. jumped over! the slow.  dog');
$test =~ s/([\.\?!]\s*[a-z])/\U$1/mg;
print $test;
```

Result is:

```
The quick.Brown fox. Jumped over! The slow.  Dog
```

I'm not having much luck figuring out how to force a period and single whitespace.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't know perl but maybe `([.?!])\S` replace with `$1 `.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the first letter following `., ?, !` will be lower-case?  What about this, for example:  `the quick.Brown fox.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
my $test = ucfirst('the quick.brown fox. jumped over! the slow.  dog');
$test =~ s/[.?!]\s*([a-z]?)/. \U$1/img;
say $test;
```

As you can see, I moved the opening `(` so that the only thing captured was the letter you want to convert to uppercase.  All the parts of the match on the left hand side will be removed/replaced, capture brackets `(...)` + `$1` allow you to carry part of that across to the replacement side.

Note you generally don't need to backslash-escape things in `[...]`.

@Borodin's edit added the `?` after `[a-z]` which makes the letter optional.  This allows the punctuation and the following spaces to be normalised even if the next thing is not a letter, or if it's the end of the line.

Comment: This worked great, thanks for the explanation.
I ended up needing to exclude ".com" and ".net" from this for my purposes, ended with a negative lookahead added to the start:
`$text =~ s/(?!.com|.net)[.?!]\s*([a-z]?)/. \U$1/img;`